# Why doesn't \uccode have an effect on \scshape

Tags: fonts, small-caps

I thought I had a simple answer to [Automatically getting “V” as the capital letter for “u” when typesetting latin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131103/22413) by writing something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mytextsc}[1]{%%"
  \begingroup
  \uccode`\u=`\V
  \textsc{#1}%%'
  \endgroup}

\newcommand{\mytextuc}[1]{%%"
  \begingroup
  \uccode`\u=`\V
  \uppercase{#1}%%'
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\mytextsc{Lurem} non-upper case text

\mytextuc{Lurem} non-upper case text

\end{document}
```

But my use of `\uccode` has no effect in the definition of `\mytextsc`.  Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\uccode` sets up the map that is used by `\uppercase` to map *tokens*  such as `v` to `V`.

`\scshape` does not involve uppercaseing or changing tokens at all, it is just a font design choice like sans serif or italic etc, a font in which the lower case letter slots are filled with glyphs that are traditionally used for capital letters.